# Sinatra-assetpack not compiling Less files in Classic type Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, less, sinatra-assetpack

I cannot figure out how to do this. All my main .less files are in `/app/css/less`, with @import'ed files in `/app/css/less/bootstrap`. My main stylesheet is `/app/css/less/style.less` which should be compiled to '/public/css/style.css'.

Using a classic Sinatra app structure (not base), I have the following in various files (unrelated code left out):
****Gemfile

```
# encoding: utf-8
source :rubygems

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'less'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.2.0.rc.1'
gem 'sinatra-partial'
gem 'sinatra-assetpack', :git => 'git://github.com/rupe/sinatra-assetpack.git', :require => 'sinatra/assetpack'
```

****myapp.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sinatra/partial'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'less'

assets do
  Less.paths .lt.lt "#{settings.root}/app/css/less"
  Less.paths .lt.lt "#{settings.root}/app/css/less/bootstrap"
  serve '/css', from: '/app/css/less'
  css :style, [
    '/css/style.css'
  ]
  prebuild true
end
```

****layout.haml

```
!= css :style, :media => 'screen'
```

Which produces this stylesheet related tag in the served up html:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.496718.css" media="screen"
```

but does not actually compile the file `style.49718.css`. In fact, it doesn't compile any files at all.

note: The git branch, referred to in Gemfile, is a copy of the 'pbaker' branch that fixed Less support (supposedly). I have tried the standard gem, and other versions, all without any luck.

What could be the possible cause(s)?

NOTE: A related question, but not duplicate (as it refers to `@import` issues only), can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099319/how-do-i-get-twitter-bootstraps-less-files-to-work-with-sinatra-assetpack/12099530#12099530).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem was, I had to use the `--all` option when running `bundle package`. So `bundle package --all` created a local cache of my custom git fork of the `sinatra-assetpack` gem, and all works "as advertised" now :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative (and for google's posterity), there's been a bunch of work on the AssetPack gem recently (with less support now built in).

This Gist has a full example of less support: https://gist.github.com/4652773.

Comment: It's broken again for me (using latest official gem, not my fork). I tried the setup in the above gist, but no luck, just an empty `styles.32455.css` file is created.

Comment: Ok, got it to work again, but only if just ONE file is included in the  `['path/to/style.css']` block and `serve :css, from: 'path/to/less'` is omitted. So to serve up multiple LESS files (without @imports) you have to create a `css :css, [...]` for each.